# Xamarin HybridWebView not loading url in iOS device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin HybridWebView to load url's inside the Xamarin.Forms application. It doesn't load the url in iOS devices. Can any one advice on this.

This is the code use to load url in xaml file:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView"
                   Uri="http://www.google.com"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I have added the following key in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: There's no official HybridWebView view in Xamarin, can you link to the library/sample/code that you're using to implement the actual HybridWebView?

Comment: Can you try this link ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Comment: Ok, do you see any exceptions on the console when you try to load the URL? If the ATS policy is not set up correctly, there should be an error.

Comment: No i didn't see any error. I tried with general Xamarin WebView. It worked fine.

Comment: could you show your HybridWebViewRenderer ?maybe it is helpful for finding the error.

Comment: i solved this applying correct Xamarin.iOS codes. Thanks for everyone for the support.